# Counting the group of data in a column that is dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I'm using Mysql and CodeIgniters MVC framework to retrieve my data within a particular timeframe. Currently I'm using the following model class to retrieve my data count from the status column.

Model Class:

```
public function summary($st_date,$end_date){
        $this->db->select("
            SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Draft' THEN 1 END) AS draft,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Unpublish' THEN 1 END) AS unpublish,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Publish' THEN 1 END) AS publish,
            SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Action' THEN 1 END) AS action,
        );
        $this->db->where('added_date >=', $st_date);
        $this->db->where('added_date <=', $end_date);
        return $this->db->get('crm_listings');
   }
```

And this in my controller class:

```
$data_sum = $this->user_model->summary($startDate,$endDate)->result();

$output .= '
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Draft</th>
                    <th>Unpublish</th>
                    <th>Publish</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
              ';
           if(isset($data_sum) && count($data_sum) > 0)
           {
            foreach($data_sum as $row ){
               $draft = $row->draft ? $row->draft : 0;
               $unpublish = $row->unpublish ? $row->unpublish : 0;
               $publish = $row->publish ? $row->publish : 0;
               $action = $row->action ? $row->action : 0;
            $output .= '
               <tr>
               <td>'.$draft.'</td>
               <td>'.$unpublish.'</td>
               <td>'.$publish.'</td>
               <td>'.$action.'</td>
               </tr>
            ';
            }
           }
           else
           {
              $output .= '<tr>
                 <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
                 </tr>';
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
```

But now I've noticed that there are more than just these 4 options in the database, so I want to figure out a way to make this count dynamic instead of me specifying `SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Draft' THEN 1 END) AS draft`, the draft variable should be dynamic and should accordingly reflect in my controller class which has my display code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a GROUP BY in your query

```
public function summary($st_date,$end_date){
    $this->db->select("
        status_to,
        SUM(1) AS sum_status
    ");
    $this->db->where('added_date >=', $st_date);
    $this->db->where('added_date <=', $end_date);
    $this->db->group_by('status_to');
    return $this->db->get('crm_listings');
}
```

Than in the controller:

```
if(isset($data_sum) && count($data_sum) > 0){
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach($data_sum as $row){
        $sum = $row->sum_status ? $row->sum_status : 0;
        $output .= '<td>'.$sum.'</td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

If u need the columns in a specific order just store the totals in an array like that:

```
if(isset($data_sum) && count($data_sum) > 0){
    $totals = array(
        "Draft" => 0,
        "Unpublish" => 0,
        "Publish" => 0,
        "Action" => 0,
    );
    foreach($data_sum as $row){
        $totals[$row->status_to] = $row->sum_status;
    }
    $output .= '
           <tr>
           <td>'.$totals["Draft"].'</td>
           <td>'.$totals["Unpublish"].'</td>
           <td>'.$totals["Publish"].'</td>
           <td>'.$totals["Action"].'</td>
           </tr>
        ';
}
```

Comment: Okay then how do I show it with the count in my controller class?

Comment: I edited the response with the code for the controller

Comment: I tried this and it put all of my entries under the draft column. This is what it used to look like https://imgur.com/1BnqKhC and this is what it looks like now https://imgur.com/a/h4G06OO

Comment: can you **var_dump** the $data_sum result?